# c# file read/write lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex, streamreader

I'm uring `StreamReader` to read/write from/to a file in two threads, read in one and write in other. I want that these two don't occur at the same time. What lock should I use? I looked at some examples but they were using `FileStream.Lock` and I'm not sure whether I can use that with `StreamReader` so please clarify.

Comment: just curious ..but do these have to be in different threads.. also do you have a sample of the code that you are using

Comment: @DJKRAZE yes, these have to be in different threads. The thread that is writing actually fetches some data from a remote server and appends some of it to the file.

Comment: You can't use StreamReader to write to a file.  Surely you meant something else but there's little point in guessing that you need anything more than a simple *lock*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own lock:

```
class Example
{
    private static readonly object SyncRoot = new object();

    void ReadOrWrite()
    {
        lock(SyncRoot)
        {
            // Perform a read or write
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: symcroot can be just `Object`? I mean not some subclass of object ?

Comment: it's static, so it should handle multiple threads. it doens't need to be sub-classed; the only purpose of the SyncRoot object is to be locked

Comment: ok. and it can't have any problem with Example being a subclass of `Form`, can it?

Comment: No. The type of the outer class will not matter

Comment: Do I need to unlock it? I can't find any unlock keyword. I guess the brackets will automatically take care of that.

Comment: Yup. There's no unlock keyword. The locking control block follows the same rules as any other control block scope

Answer (score 1):

you could use a semaphore

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx

Comment: A semaphore will work, but if the order in which things happen are important, there is no queuing when using a semaphore.  There are no guarantees what thread will get the lock after it's released.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to locking the file itself, use the "lock" keyword.  Otherwise, you will throw an exception when trying to work with a locked file

```
private object lockObject = new Object();

//  Code in thread that reads
lock(lockObject)
{
     // Open the file and do something
    // Be sure to close it when done.
}


// Somewhere else in another thread
lock(lockObject)
{
    // Open the file for writing and do somethign with it
    // Be sure to close it when done.
}
```

Comment: @prongs: Yes it is. A thread waiting to acquire it will be put to sleep by the OS until the lock becomes available.